# Check if combination appears in lists in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, combinations

I have two large dataframes something like this:

```
df1:
             A  time
0    [a, b, c]   122
1    [a, d, e]    45
2    [b, c, e]    64

df2:
  Origin  Destination 
0      a            b   
1      b            c   
2      b            e   
3      d            e
```

Now I want to compare the two, so that the code checks if the combination of Origin and Destination from df2 appears in the lists in column A of df1. If this combination appears I want this combination added in new columns in df1. If this combination does not appear in a list nothing needs to happen.

Also if there is multiple combinations for 1 list I want to add another row so that there will be one row per combination. If I would compare df1 with df2, the new df1 needs to look something like this:

```
df1:
             A  time  Origin  Destination
0    [a, b, c]   122       a            b
0    [a, b, c]   122       b            c
1    [a, d, e]    45       d            e
2    [b, c, e]    64       b            c
2    [b, c, e]    64       b            e
```

I have tried something with for loops but I have not managed to solve it. If somebody would help me with this problem I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I din't find an elegant way, but you could try something like this :

```py
# data first
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']],
                    "time": [122, 45, 64]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Origin": ['a', 'b', 'b', 'd'],
                    "Destination": ['b', 'c', 'e', 'e']})

# an empty dataframe in which rows will be added iteratively (not optimum)
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "time", "Origin", "Destination"])
out_index = 0


for name, row in df1.iterrows():
     # for each row in df1, find Origin and Destination in df2 include in row.A
     mask = df2.Origin.isin(row.A) & df2.Destination.isin(row.A)   

     # df2[mask] is a dataframe, the following will "append" this dataframe to row in out
     for name_mask, row_mask in df2[mask].iterrows():
        new_row = pd.concat([row, row_mask])
        out.loc[out_index, :] = new_row
        out_index += 1

print(out)
```

Which leads to :

```
     A time Origin Destination
0  [a, b, c]  122      a           b
1  [a, b, c]  122      b           c
2  [a, d, e]   45      d           e
3  [b, c, e]   64      b           c
4  [b, c, e]   64      b           e
```

Note the solution I wrote is highly unoptimized and could be quite long on heavy dataframe